# parent and child process using fork

Tags: linux, process, fork

Under Linux when I call the `fork()` system call the parent and child processes share the same data. What kind of data does it mean? (e.g. heap data or something?)

I mean if there is a copy of all memory (stack, heap, and text) then this is inefficient. There must be something else happening.

Copy-on-write tells me that until there is a write everything is not duplicated.

Comment: They are the same process with different process ID. Everything is identical apart from that

Comment: You've changed your question so that it now has a very different meaning. Now it is not clear what the question really is. Yes, the pages are copy on write. ALL the pages. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: Yes I would like to know that there is not duplication because if there was that would be inefficient, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The parent and child processes do not share any data. Not in the sense that a change by one process will be seen by the other process. At the time of the fork the child process is an exact duplicate of the parent process in terms of data (but not everything is duplicated - see the fork man page for exact details). For data all global, heap and stack are duplicated. But again, note that it is "duplicated" not "shared".

Comment: I can't be sure from your wording, but what I think you're saying is not correct. The data is not duplicated on fork. Linux employs a copy-on-write mechanism. Only the bare minimum amount of data is duplicated. See the `NOTES` section on the `man 2 fork` page.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I should be more precise with my wording. I meant the process address space. But on the other hand I'm not sure the question is really going to that level and it might just confuse the issue.